# What is the equivalent of 127.255.255.255 for OS/X machines so I can test broadcast udp packets without a network?

Tags: networking, mac-osx, udp, multicast

I am trying to test my program that makes use of broadcast UDP (not multicast!). In Linux, I can use the 127.255.255.255:64651 address and everything works beautifully, in other words, I send a packet to 127.255.255.255:64651 and multiple clients listening on that port get the packet. A real broadcast example!

Unfortunately on my OS/X machine (Mountain Lion) the same example does not work.

Is there any way I can get 127.255.255.255 to work on mac machines? Any other solution to get broadcast working on my mac machine without a network?

Note: It has to be broadcast, not multicast.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `127.255.255.255`, on Mac OS X try using `224.255.255.255` as an alternative.

Comment: 224.255.255.255 does not work. I found the right one, but since this is off-topic according to the moderators, I won't bother saying it. Nobody cares anyways!

Comment: JohnPristine, it is sad that you haven't posted the answer. Now I have to do my own quest :(

Answer (score 1):

`127.255.255.255` should not work. Strange!

Use your network broadcast address, that's what it's for.

For instance, if your network is `192.168.10.0/24`, your broadcast address is `192.168.10.255`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Mikey, but as I said I do not have a network to get this address from. The machine is offline. :)

Comment: Add a fake interface or add an IP to your loopback interface.